# Removing css class property?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I want remove "ui-widget-content" class from below code
my code consist lot many places with that class
Here is the sample code.

```
<pre>
<form id="clientForm">
<div id="clientData">
<div id="gbox_grid_1" class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
</div>
<div id="gview_grid_1" class="ui-jqgrid-view">
</div>
<table id="grid_1" class="ui-jqgrid-btable">
<tr class="ui-subgrid subGridLevl2">
<td class="ui-widget-content subgrid-cell">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</pre>
```

can any one help me in removing the class in optimized way

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery remove() functionality , In your case as

```
$('td').removeClass('ui-widget-content');
```

basics [here](http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of these, and don't want to delete them directly from the file, you can use jQuery. This single line will remove them.

```
$('*').removeClass('ui-widget-content');
```

However, if you want them to be removed from the css file.. I'd think just to open the css file in any text editor, and use the find and replace method.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div td").removeClass("ui-widget-content");
});
```

Comment: Even class present in tr likewise

Comment: $("div td") these are selectors if you add tr in selector it'll remove class from tr as well if you want to remove class from entire page use * like this $("*").removeClass('class name');

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using jquery ,
Use the following :

`$( "td" ).removeClass( "ui-widget-content" );`